# Spring HandlerExceptionResolver in unable to Handle exception thrown during conversion from object to json

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, exception

In our Spring MVC application,we have created a component which is responsible for handling the exception.

```
@Component
public class RestResponseStatusExceptionResolver  extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver{

}

Now we have a controller and inside it,we have a method,which has below signature.

@RequestMapping(value = "/getBhaQuoteItems", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, BHAQuotationBean> getBhaQuoteItems(@RequestParam(value = "quoteNumber") String quoteNumber,{
    Map<String, BHAQuotationBean> map = null;
    //call to service layer,which populate map
    return  map;
   }
```

We were getting 500 internal error as HTTP response,After some analysis,we solved the problem,it was issue related to Object --> JSON conversion.

But my question is,do we have any mechanism to handle the exception,as in our case the exception was coming in Java Object --> JSON conversion after return statement,and Spring HandlerExceptionResolver in unable to handle it.